# Maxscript - Object height to match Spline Length using?

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

I am new to Maxscript.
I'm looking for a solution to wire a length of a spline to the height of a box.
I found this script:

```
dependsOn $Line01 $Box01
( --length
local SL = getSegLengths $Line01 1
local SLC = SL.count
SL[SLC]
) --length
```

I tried to apply that script to my scene and newly created objects, box01 and line01, I run the script but nothing happens, and I don't get any error.
How to make the script to work, and to match line length to a height of a box object?

EDIT:
Thread where I found script:
http://forums.cgsociety.org/showthread.php?t=309679

Answer (score 0):

Create a box and a line (with one segment only) and run this script. Move the vertex of the line, the height of the box should change with it.

```
str = "dependsOn $Line001 $Box001
(
local SL = getSegLengths $Line001 1
local SLC = SL.count
SL[SLC]
)"

$Box001.height.controller = float_script ()
c = $Box001.height.controller
c.script = str
```

Make sure that the object names match. You can do so manually too by assigning a float script controller to the box height and pasting the `str` contents in it.